# How to ban a client in client_server chat in java

Tags: java, server, client

I have implemented Client_server chat in java, all in my code work nice but I need to add a new  feature that allow different privilege levels for users, normal users and super users. Super users have the ability to ban other users permanently from further conversations by sending a special message to the server. **How should I do to ban a user.**
 I have server class, Client class and chat class.The code is very long but it is similar to this link code, 
https://github.com/abhi195/Chat-Server
Help please!
Thank you for hand!

Comment: If it is permanent can't you just interrupt the Client thread?

Comment: interrupting should be at server class?

Comment: The thread object should be visible to interrupt it, so if you declare it in Server than you can interrupt it in Server class, otherwise you can pass it to Superuser, and it can call interrupt on that Thread object and suspend it. Note, you need to worry about the InterruptedException as the interrupted client may sleep when you interrupt him.

Comment: Do you know if there is some link or web side that is good to learn about interrupting   or something like my question.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop
But try to google it to find more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer I will try